# Create a blank word document with Apache POI

Tags: android, apache-poi

I try to create a blank word document, so I read tutorials about Apache POI, but the installation process failed.

I have added libs file in my project's lib folder, but I got an error of type **Duplicate file exception**.

The duplicated file was LICENCE.

As I read on other users' question, I add this in my build gradle :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

But now, I get this error :

**Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. 
This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. 
The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.**

**Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location;**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Take a look at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54084 and https://github.com/pjfanning/xmlbeans regarding the xmlbeans duplication

Comment: I do not understand how to use them to solve my problem. I got the same problem.

Comment: In some environments (such as Android), xmlbeans-2.6.0 redefines some classes (in your case, org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location). PJ Fanning created a fork of xmlbeans that fixes this issue. If you build xmlbeans using the code on github or fetch his jar from maven.org, the "already added" error will go away. http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.github.pjfanning%22

Comment: I got a ClassNotFoundException for "javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory" when I tried to instantiate a new XWPFDocument. Which jar files do you use to have a working project with Apache POI ? I tried all of them, I changed the xmlbeans2.6.0 for the 2.6.2. Nothing's working actually...

Comment: Try asking on the POI Users List, https://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html. I am not familiar with running POI under Android's VM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414166/react-native-npm-start-with-watchman-error/40441481#40441481

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache POI

Comment: apache xmlbeans 3.0.0 has been released and contains all the fixes the forked version of xmlbeans mentioned above